# MacBook Pro 10.9.1 loading web pages very slow over 116Mbps Airport Extreme 802.11ac

Tags: macos, airport, dns

This is driving me crazy.  I have a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.1 connecting to the internet via an Airport Extreme 802.11ac.  Speedtest shows I am pulling 116Mbps.

A week ago or so I installed HMA! Proxy client and ever since I installed that the speed in which any browser opens pages has slowed to a crawl.

I've since "uninstalled" that application and flushed the DNS cache and rebooted seemingly a thousand times but where before if I opened a flurry of tabs, even ten or more one right after another, they'd snap right open but now everything takes forever to load.

Figured I'd ask for suggestions here before I do the dreaded OS reinstall.

Thanks.

Ping to Google

```
64 bytes from 167.206.145.158: icmp_seq=0 ttl=59 time=12.752 ms
64 bytes from 167.206.145.158: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=15.842 ms
64 bytes from 167.206.145.158: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=14.400 ms
64 bytes from 167.206.145.158: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=14.633 ms
64 bytes from 167.206.145.158: icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=14.490 ms
```

Comment: Proxy will cut down your speed to 1/2. Use What is My IP to see if you are still going thru a proxy.

Comment: @Buscar웃 definitely not going through a proxy anymore...

Comment: Open your Browser and reset the proxy settings.

Comment: Is your IP what it should be or does it show you in over the rainbow land. Ping Goolge and report results here.

Comment: @Buscar웃 ok will post ping results in OP

Comment: You Ping looks great, so I am without a clue. Please research what the Heide My Ass proxy installation did, and how to uninstall it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is still with the HMA proxy, even if your Google ping looks good.

Since the HMA proxy software is available in Chrome and Firefox, please check those for proxy settings, and remove the add on if it is still there.

Also check your

> system-preferences-network-advanced-proxies

and uncheck all of them.

[image: proxy]

I would try the Safari browser since it did not get impacted by the HMA install.

Run the [WhatismyIP](http://www.whatismyip.com/) in all 3 browsers and make sure you get same result.